# gulp-inject not loading all bower components

Tags: angularjs, bower, yeoman-generator, bower-install, gulp-inject

I'm using the yeoman generator-gulp-angular to scaffold my app. I installed ng-18next with bower, and the package and it's dependency were both correctly installed in the bower_components directory. However, when I run gulp serve and view the source the components aren't being injected into page, so I get a module instantiation error. If I hard code the deps into the page there are no errors. I also tried bower install --save and the deps are inserted into the bower.json file correctly. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had hard-coded script references in index.html. Even though they were commented, this caused them not to be injected with wiredep.